# How to get relevant data from another website in asp.Net MVC

Tags: web-services, remote-access, remote-server

before starting thank you for your time.

I am creating a web project in asp.net MVC which is kind of a customer service. Before this project started, we used to have this service from another call-center. Let's say a customer calls, customer service agent fill forms and our related responsible login to their website and view data.

Now, with my project we are trying to do this on our own. Customer logs in, fill form and post. Our responsible logs in and do some action on it. Both the previous service and our's have almost the same fields.

I also want to show call-center created data, in my project as another page like (call-center data). But I almost have no idea about what I can ask and what I can research. I read something about webservices and remote calls.

What I want to achieve, is the process behind this. Are they going to create some codes and give me some related link I will use in my project. Or do I need to provide them my database or code and they will do some action(which is not my preference). Also, should my project and theirs must be using same database(mssql) in order to achieve this ?

I hope I am clear enough to ask my question, please ask anything.Btw, my project is ready to use except for this so, I hope there will be no problem with my code section that you would ask.

Thank you so much.

Note : I used DB first approach with ADO.NET. Using EF and LINQ in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web API to share data from multiple platforms.
Kindly go through the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms